# SQL Server Open File From Image Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have a field in a SQL Server 2005 DB of type 'image' that contains documents, mostly pdfs.  When I view the field in the database, it looks as though the data is stored as a hex string.  I have extensively googled and came up with the VB.net function below to convert the field to an actual file, but it only outputs a file containing the string of hex characters rather than the file that the field is supposed to represent.

This is a sample of the fields' data (I have truncated it for privacy purposes):

```
0x1F8B0800000000000400EDBD07601C499625262F6DCA7B7F4AF
```

And the function I have written to convert the field to a document:

```
    Private Sub SimpleButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SimpleButton1.Click

    sql = New MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connectionString)

    Dim cmd As New MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("SELECT docdata FROM temp.temp_docs WHERE docid = " + TextEdit1.Text, sql)

    sql.Open()

    Dim dr As MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    dr.Read()

    Dim b(dr.GetBytes(0, 0, Nothing, 0, Integer.MaxValue) - 1) As Byte

    dr.GetBytes(0, 0, b, 0, b.Length)

    dr.Close()

    sql.Close()

    Dim DestFilePath As String = "C:\... \Desktop\" & String.Format("{0:hhmmss}", DateTime.Now) & ".pdf"

    Dim fs As New System.IO.FileStream(DestFilePath, IO.FileMode.Create, IO.FileAccess.Write)

    fs.Write(b, 0, b.Length)

    fs.Close()

End Sub
```

Can anyone spot where I am going wrong? And is it possible to open the file straight from a query in SQL server?

Comment: Shouldn't you being using the SQL ADO.NET provider rather than the MySQL provider?

Comment: We are using a DTS package to transfer the data to a MySQL client which is where we are reading the data from.  We have confirmed there is no problem with the data transformation, so the function above reads the same data that was in SQL Server from MySQL. I probably should have mentioned that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMAGE fields do not contain 'hex strings'. They contain binary data which you read it as a binary stream using [`SqlBytes.Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlbytes.stream.aspx). You copy the stream into your desired file using [`Stream.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx).